# html buttons width in magnific popup, increase the size on ipad

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, ipad

My Html button has the normal size on the desktop version, and when I scale the window down to iPad resolution its fit in, but when I test it on my iPad the button width makes its own size.

image of the desktop version where it works fine: http://i59.tinypic.com/29cl6ht.png

image of the ipad version where it don´t work: http://i62.tinypic.com/5cyck0.jpg

html:

```
<button class="artistmoresearch" type="button"></button>
```

css:

```
.artistmoresearch, .videomoresearch, .releasemoresearch{
    width: 8%;
    font: 700 85px arial;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    top: 4px;
    bottom: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    background: @grey;  
    color:#888;
    border-bottom: 2px solid darken(@grey, 8%);
    .roundedcorners;
}
```

Comment: you must put your code into question

Comment: like daaaaaaaaaaaaat?